# Cannot access image site(IIS) directly

Tags: asp.net, image, iis

I am talking about IIS and ASP.NET application. Currently I decide to create one web application in one site (http://domain.com) and another one site for keeping images (http://images.domain.com). After a little work, I found the problem of accessing the path for creating the images from web application site to image site.  One solution that is appeared on my thought is using Web Service. But I still want to hear if there are other solution for solving this problem from you guys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few options, most of them applicable if both sites are on the same computer, or even on the same network domain :

1. Give the windows user that acts as the identity of the main site's application pool, access permissions to the Images' site folder.
2. use Impersonation to access the other images' site folders with the right permissions.
3. Another option is to have both sites run as the same windows user

other then that, haveing a web service to push files to the Images site is a great and scalable solution.

Comment: Fortunately, both sites are on the same server. what about using FTP?

Comment: FTP is an option as well, you can easily use it from C# using `FtpWebRequest`. However if both sites are on the same server and you have no plans to seperate them, then any of my suggested methods should be easier to configure.